# Workflow wont run on document libraries whch have versioning enabled

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I was having a issue where I had setup a workflow to send out an email when a new document was uploaded into a document library that had versioning (Approval) turned on. The condition for the workflow was to check if the "Approval Status" was "2;#Pending" if it was then send out the email.

The problem I have is that they workflow gets stuck in the "Starting" state, if I then go into the document library and set the "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" option to "No", the workflow then starts and completes successfully.

How can I ensure that they workflow works if I then set the "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" option to "Yes"?

I am running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise SP2

Thanks,

Comment: Is the document checked in when the workflow stalls? Versioning and check-in/check-out are two different things. A workflow can also wait for a document to be checked in, then continue.

Comment: yes the document is checked-in